# Super inplace controls in_place_select displays incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the super_inplace_controls plugin to allow users to edit fields on the "show" page.  However, I'm running into an issue with the in_place_select function.  Here is my view:

```
<p>
    <b>Status:</b>
    <%= in_place_select :incident, :incident_status, :choices => @statuses.map { |e| [e.name, e.id] } %>
</p>
```

This is in the 'Incident' view.  IncidentStatus is a separate table that has_many Incidents.  In the Incident controller, I retrieve @statuses like so:

```
@statuses = IncidentStatus.find(:all)
```

Everything works fine for the in_place_select, except the original display.  In my browser, it shows:

```
Status:  #<IncidentStatus:0x1033147d8>
```

Which means it's not grabbing the current incident_status.name, but it's just changing the object to a string.  I'm not sure how to fix this!  When I click on the "IncidentStatus:0x1033147d8", everything works properly and I can select the proper fields.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It turns out you can pass in :display_text as an option.  So I did the following:

```
<%= in_place_select :incident, :incident_status, :choices => @statuses.map { |e| [e.name, e.id] }, :display_text => @status.name %>
```